# Data parsley pattern add äöü

Tags: html

I want to add the special characters äöü in my data parsley pattern

Here is what i got:
['data-parsley-pattern'] = '/^(?=[a-zA-Z]+.*\d).+$/';

Could you help me out on this one?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a backslash to escape

```
['data-parsley-pattern'] = '/^(?=[a-zA-Z\ä\ö\ü]+.*\d).+$/'
```